# Minimize busywork, javascript, reducing function to make it automatic

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using javascript to scroll through images.

Anyway someone can help me reduce this code so that it can read how many lines of code are available so that I am able to insert images in the .html file instead of messing with the .js file, too.

It's an image slider based on CSS:
https://codepen.io/Groundedelectron/pen/ZaMrKa

```
 <div id="images">
   <img id="image1" src="..." />
   <img id="image2" src=".." />
   <img id="image3" src="..." />
   <img id="image4" src="..." />
</div>

<div id="slider">
   <a href="#image1">1</a>
   <a href="#image2">2</a>
   <a href="#image3">3</a>
   <a href="#image4">4</a>
</div>
```

By clicking on each link gets me to see the image. I added a button:

```
<button id="scrollright" hidden>Scroll right</button>
```

In Javascript I have:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { // space key maps to keycode `27`
    $('#scrollright').click();
  }
});


var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var links = slider.getElementsByTagName("a");
var cyclecount = 0;

function scrollrightfunc(){
  if(cyclecount == 0){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 1){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 2){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 3){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 4){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
}
```

With each right arrow key press I can scroll to the next image.  Much appreciated for your help!

Comment: Yes, and so?  You have not asked a question.  Questions have a question mark. Like so, see?  Even if you wanted to ask a question, it just sounds like you want some to do all of your work for you, which is not what SO is for.

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry, the library was closing, and for all the questions I have asked someone has always wrote something.  I saw it when I posted, if you could help me edit it out that would be much appreciated.  See my history of questions I'm not asking for free work, I'm asking for help.

Comment: Nevertheless, you failed to ask a question.  Please edit your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var cyclecount = 0;
    var cyclenumber = 0;


    function scrollrightfunc(){
      if(cyclecount == cyclenumber){
      links[cyclecount].click();
      cyclecount++;
      cyclenumber++;
      return;
      }
    }
```

This replaces (and so forth to infiniti)

```
function scrollrightfunc(){
  if(cyclecount == 0){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 1){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 2){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 3){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
  if(cyclecount == 4){
    links[cyclecount].click();
    cyclecount++;
    return;
  }
}
```